# C# in my unit test i want to see if it is null or an empty string

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mspec, shouldly

I'm using Machine spec / Shouldly and testing a mapping profile (mundane work). The mapping expectations are sometimes inconsistent. Sometimes I am seeing an `""` explicit empty string get returned and sometimes it's a null value. Since we're mapping to a spreadsheet it doesn't matter on that front but it gets a little annoying when asserting.

Is there a way in Machine spec to do something like `assertionValue.ShouldEqual(null || "")` ?

Comment: http://docs.shouldly-lib.net/docs/shouldbenullorempty

Comment: @mche You could try C# 8.0, which will force a type to be non null unless specified otherwise.  Might reduce some of the inconsistencies you're experiencing.

Comment: @Greg is any version of C# 8.0 even released? To my knowledge it doesn't even have a predicted release date

Comment: @Dave I thought so, Mad's said they were allowing the community to actually use to receive feedback due to the massive changes in this iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Assert on the outcome of string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: I too think it will.

Comment: While this would work it’s not a good answer to the question, which is essentially “how do I make this assertion using Shouldly?”.   Your answer is not how to do it with the Shouldy library.

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty().ShouldBeTrue();