# Why does casting the result from a controller in a unit test return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am in the process of equipping my sources with unit tests, but I made a mistake here.
What can I do at this point if the value is really "null"?
Is that even possible?

I have tried to figure out how others solve it but with the following thread I don't quite get along.
[C# in my unit test i want to see if it is null or an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183102/c-sharp-in-my-unit-test-i-want-to-see-if-it-is-null-or-an-empty-string)

--> If I use IsNullOrEmpty() like in the example above, how does that look like in my code snippet?

This is the affected area in my unit test:

```
Assert.That(deviceInfo.SerialNumber == null);
```

The following error message appears:

**Message: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source**

Edit - This is what my environment looks like:

Here is the class with the DeviceDetails object which has all information in the body.

```
public virtual IActionResult DevicesIdGet([FromRoute][Required]string id)
{
    var device = _deviceManager.GetDevice(id);

    if (device == null)
        return NotFound();

    var deviceDetails = new DeviceDetails
    {
        IsOnline = device.IsOnline(),
        SerialNumber = null
    };

    return Ok(deviceDetails);
}
```

Unit-Test

```
 private Device _testDevice;

 [SetUp]
 public void SetUp()
    {
        _testDevice = new Device
        {
            Id = 1,
            DeviceType = 1,
            DisplayName = "TestDevice",
            IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),
            IpAddressString = "127.0.0.1"
        };
    }

[Test]
public void If_DeviceIsAvailable_Then_DeviceIdIsSelected()
{
    // ARRANGE
    var deviceManagerMock = new Mock<IDeviceManager>();
    deviceManagerMock.Setup(manager => manager.GetDevices(false))
        .Returns(new List<Device>
                 {
                     _testDevice
                 })
        .Verifiable();

    var subject = new DevicesApiController(deviceManagerMock.Object);

    // ACT
    var result = subject.DevicesIdGet("1");

    // ASSERT
    var deviceInfos = result as IEnumerable<DeviceDetails>;
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos.Single();
    Assert.That(deviceInfo.IsOnline == true);
    Assert.That(deviceInfo.SerialNumber == null);
}
```

Comment: What Test Framework is in use? Please add complete stacktrace and some context. A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: That line almost certainly isn't the one producing the exception, unless `deviceInfo.SerialNumber` is a poorly written property with a `get` that can throw exceptions. What else is in your test method?

Comment: Are you looking for this: [Assert.IsNull(object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isnull?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_IsNull_System_Object_) ?

Comment: Please post complete code with method

Comment: Can you click and see this?
[Link to DeviceApi](https://rextester.com/UVFUX64212)

Comment: Please post code in your question, not as a link. You can [edit] your question directly.

Comment: _"If I use IsNullOrEmpty() like in the example above, how does that look like in my code snippet?"_ : `Assert.That(string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceInfo.SerialNumber));`

Comment: To me, this looks like an exception thrown by your code somewhere and not a problem with the Assert. Do you have a method somewhere in your code with a parameter named `source`?

Comment: Consider adding a `Assert.That(deviceInfo != null);`

Comment: You're mocking `GetDevices`, but the method calls `GetDevice`...

Comment: @HansKilian, no there is no 'source' parameter

Comment: `var deviceInfos = result as IEnumerable<DeviceDetails>` almost certainly produces a `deviceInfos` that is `null`, because `Ok(deviceDetails)` is not going to be an `IEnumerable`. The method throwing is `Enumerable.Single`, which is an extension method with a first parameter named (you guessed it) `source`. If you used a cast rather than `as`, you'd get a direct conversion error.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert, thanks for your answer. Sorry to have to ask you again, but I want to understand exactly what I did wrong. Why should IEnumerable not work here? If I adjust the cast as the following, would 

    var deviceInfos = result?.Value as IEnumerable<DeviceDetails>;

be valid and work here?

Comment: No, because `Controller.Ok` just wraps the object you give it in an `OkObjectResult`, and `DeviceDetails` is itself not an enumerable. What you should get back is an `OkObjectResult` with a `Value` that's a single `DeviceDetails`, so `var deviceDetails = (DeviceDetails) ((OkObjectResult) result).Value` should be enough. (There's no real need to hedge your bet for a `null` value or an incorrect type as the code doesn't produce it, but you could add additional asserts for that if you really wanted to be thorough.) I'm not sure there's not a cleaner pattern in MVC for this, though.

Comment: Since you're not mocking the `GetDevice`call, I'd guess that the mock returns null when you call it. That results in a `NotFound` response. So when you assume that you're getting a list of devices back, things go wrong. Stepping through the code with the debugger as the test runs will make it pretty clear what's happening, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller calls this method of `IDeviceManager`, which *is not mocked*:

```
var device = _deviceManager.GetDevice(id);
```

Not mocking that method is one cause for the exception. But if you fix it and mock that method (using `Setup` to specify a result on the mock) you'll still get the same exception. More on that later. First, here's the path your code is going down:

Because it's not mocked, the return value from calling `GetDevice` on the mock will be null, so this happens:

```
if (device == null)
    return NotFound();
```

The result of the method is a `NotFound` result.

Then, this is happening in the unit test:

```
var deviceInfos = result as IEnumerable<DeviceDetails>;
var deviceInfo = deviceInfos.Single();
```

`result` is a `NotFoundResult`. `result as IEnumerable<DeviceDetails>` returns `null`.

So you're effectively doing this:

```
IEnumerable<DeviceDetails> deviceInfos = null;
var deviceInfo = deviceInfos.Single();
```

The `source` parameter passed to the `Single` method is null, hence the exception.

---

If you mock `GetDevice`, you'll still get the same error for almost exactly the same reason. Now your code will return an `OkObjectResult` instead of a `NotFoundResult`. You'll try to cast that as `IEnumerable<DeviceDetails>`, it will still be `null`, and you'll get the same exception.

What you need is to get the value from the `OkObjectResult`, like this:

```
var actionResult = subject.DevicesIdGet("1") as OkObjectResult;
var deviceInfos = actionResult.Value as IEnumerable<DeviceDetails> ;
var deviceInfo = deviceInfos.Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of code posted, it appears deviceInfo can be null. You can you the following:

```
 if (deviceInfo == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(“source”);

 // rest of the code
```